# Allow all ips in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGIN django

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework, ip, django-csrf

How to allows all/ any ips in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGIN of django
Backend django restapi are running and frontend is on angular in one system and we are trying to access  with system ip in another system, i am able to access frontend and while accessing backend POST method API's are not working it's showing not found in csrf trusted origins.
In settings.py i made get dynamic ips.

```
import socket
def get_ipaddress(): 
    
   host_name = socket.gethostname()
   ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
   return "http://"+ip_address+":4200"

ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=[get_ipaddress()]
```

Tried to use csrf_excempt , but it's not working.
Version of django4.0.1,
Angular 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
socket.gethostbyname(host_name.local)
```

When used the above line in the get_ipaddress, it got worked

Answer (score 3):

For CSRF you need only to whitelist/allow the IP of the server where your angular app is hosted. While you are running angular app you should whitelist the url you access your angular app in browser
e.g: `"http://localhost:4200"` or `http://192.168.1.1:4200`. or `https://whateveryourwebappurlis.com`.

This is the URL you use to load the app in browser. You need to whitelist this.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=["http://localhost:4200", "https://whateveryourwebappis.com"]
```

Make sure that you are passing this is in the origin header of your request to django app.

Read more at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins

In case you already haven't whitelisted the methods and headers, please do that as well in your settings.

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=False

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://yourwhitelistedip.com",
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
'DELETE',
'GET',
'OPTIONS',
'PATCH',
'POST',
'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

Comment: backend and front end in same server(192.10.39.2), i think my get_ipaddress function will add servers ip address to CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS, when are trying to access 192.10.39.2:4200 from other system in same network, its working for all, except POST methods.

Comment: Have you whitelisted the header and methods as well for CORS? I have updated the answer with details